# Keras predict_generator and Image generator

Tags: keras

How to use ImageDataGenerator and predict_generator on a single JPEG file in Keras?

I am having a single jpeg and i want to predict the probability using model trained using model.fita-generator function.

Answer (score 3):

If you just have a single .jpeg, you don't need to use the ImageDataGenerator. In the code below I'm assuming you trained your model with RGB images sized 150px x 150px.

```python
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(150, 150))
img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)
img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)
img_tensor /= 255.

model.predict(img_tensor)
```

For more info, check out Francois Chollet's excellent Ipython Notebooks. Specifically, Line (In [2]) of https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn.ipynb

In this section, he looks at the intermediate activation layers for an image that wasn't in his train_generator. He loads in a model he created in another Ipython notebook: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.2-using-convnets-with-small-datasets.ipynb

Comment: Is this valid if I have trained and evaluated my model using model.train_generator and model.evaluate_generator?

Comment: Yes, as long as the image size is correct, the image color is RGB, and the model was trained on values from 0 to 1. I updated the answer to providing an example from the Keras creator's Ipython Notebooks.